# Convert ISO String to PST using Moment.js

Tags: timezone, momentjs

I am trying to convert an ISO String to PST time.  For some reason, it is converting it to my local timzone instead of to PST.  The PST for this string below is "7:40 PM" for reference.  Here is the code I am running:

```
var now = moment('2018-07-09T02:40:38.818Z').tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('MM-DD-YYYY h:mm:ss a');
alert(now);
```

JS Fiddle w/ Moment installed:

https://jsfiddle.net/john23/5gbv2csj/5/

Comment: You are missing moment-timezone **data** in the linked fiddle, See [docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/): _To use moment-timezone, you will need `moment@2.9.0+`, `moment-timezone.js`, and the `moment-timezone` data._

Comment: Alternatively, consider using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/), a new library from the Moment team.  It doesn't require a separate time zone data file.